# Cannot access administrative share in Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, file-sharing

I cannot access the administrative share (\\machine\c$) on some machines in our domain. I have admin access to these machines. This problem seems to only affect laptops, which are connected via a docking station. I can reach all desktops just fine. The laptops vary between Win 10 1803 and 1607. The laptops also vary in make/model. Windows Firewall is off.

I have been struggling with this problem for a couple weeks now. I have tried all of the usual "fixes" that are posted. Such as...

1. The LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy registry hack
2. Rejoining the domain
3. Verify file and print sharing is turned on
4. Turning off file and print sharing and turning it back on (this works! BUT 
   doesn't survive a reboot. Why?)

The exact error I get is:

```
Network Error:
Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. 
To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose.
```

Then if i choose diagnose, I get this:

```
The device or resource is not set up to accept connections on port "The File and 
printer sharing (SMB)".
```

The strange thing is that I can reach these machines via VNC or RDP.

So, does anyone have any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: If I am not mistaken SMBv1 was enabled on earlier versions of Windows 10.  What version of SMB are you using?  Are these machines connect to an AD domain?

Comment: @Ramhound In Windows Features I have SMB 1.0/CIFS Client and Server check on my machine and the affected machines. Yes, they are connected to an AD domain.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. I get denied access even when logged in as domain admin.

Comment: Are you an Administrator on the AD domain?  It is not enough to be a local Administrator in a case like this.  Which is the reason I am asking if you are an Administrator on the AD domain itself.

Comment: Do you have any policy enabled on the domain that might effect the machine from keeping File Sharing enabled?  [Disable SMB v1 in Managed Environments with Group Policy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/staysafe/2017/05/17/disable-smb-v1-in-managed-environments-with-ad-group-policy/) verify another Administrator has not implemented any of those prevented measures to disable SMBv1.  You really should use SMB v3

Comment: @Ramhound When I log in as Domain Admin, which is a separate user account in our environment, I still cannot access the administrative share.

Comment: @Ramhound I have not looked into any Group Policies yet. I will do so, and report back. Thanks

Comment: @Ramhound I did not find any Group Policies that would contribute to this behavior. However, replacing the docking station on a laptop corrected the issue on one machine. I have no idea how. Also, some laptops that I could not access yesterday, magically I can access today.